# search for a pattern and always print the first line which contains the cn

Tags: text-processing, ldap

I've a file which has the following output:

The dn: can can have more rdcPositions.

I only need the dn: which has an rdcPositions contains acme#6#

The result should print the cn and also the rdcPosition

```
dn: cn=00fa69bd-bede-4918-a017-b59b0901bb3d,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,o
 u=Vault,o=acme
rdcPosition: cn=1950,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>8946
 702990</cn><reqdate>1529318977</reqdate><startdate>1529318977</startdate><end
 date>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>1</ne
 wstatus><date>1529318977</date></change><change><date>1529319116</date><previ
 ousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>15
 29481285</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></ch
 ange></lifecycle></position>

dn: cn=010903cd-e92d-4307-bffc-4921379153c0,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,o
 u=Vault,o=acme
rdcPosition: cn=922445,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#5#<position><cn>42
 79084890</cn><reqdate>1429014997</reqdate><startdate>1429014997</startdate><e
 nddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>1</
 newstatus><date>1429014997</date></change><change><date>1429023084</date><pre
 viousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>
 1525107741</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></
 change><change><date>1525126716</date><previousstatus>6</previousstatus><news
 tatus>5</newstatus></change></lifecycle></position>
rdcPosition: cn=311982,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>97
 26910833</cn><reqdate>1528120494</reqdate><startdate>1528120494</startdate><e
 nddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>1</
 newstatus><date>1528120494</date></change><change><date>1528123478</date><pre
 viousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change></lifecycle></
 position>

dn: cn=01126aa4-af80-401b-8713-29e360868999,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,o
 u=Vault,o=acme
rdcPosition: cn=914570,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>20
 68839799</cn><reqdate>1406284665</reqdate><startdate>1406284665</startdate><e
 nddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>0</
 newstatus><date>1406284665</date></change><change><date>1406284666</date><pre
 viousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>
 1435847283</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></
 change></lifecycle></position>
rdcPosition: cn=999546,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>76
 03071057</cn><reqdate>1400325753</reqdate><startdate>1400325753</startdate><e
 nddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>0</
 newstatus><date>1400325753</date></change><change><date>1400325754</date><pre
 viousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>
 1449224475</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></
 change></lifecycle></position>
rdcPosition: cn=3513,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>2802
 042129</cn><reqdate>1406284761</reqdate><startdate>1406284761</startdate><end
 date>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>0</ne
 wstatus><date>1406284761</date></change><change><date>1406284762</date><previ
 ousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>14
 49224599</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></ch
 ange></lifecycle></position>
rdcPosition: cn=312936,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#3#<position><cn>19
 23461515</cn><reqdate>1449217172</reqdate><startdate>1449217172</startdate><e
 nddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>1</
 newstatus><date>1449217172</date></change><change><date>1449225081</date><pre
 viousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change></lifecycle></
 position>
```

Comment: Does the data have those wrapping newlines in it?

Comment: yes it does. the file is split on newline starting with dn: cn=

Answer (score 1):

The input seems to be LDIF as specified in [RFC 2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849).

I'd strongly recommend **not** to use the usual awk/sed/grep tool chain for processing LDIF because of the following reasons:

- Long attribute values lines (including dn:) are wrapped with a single space indicating the line-continuation.
- Attribute values containing non-ASCII chars will be base64-encoded.

The best solution is to use a decent LDIF parser for your favorite scripting language.

E.g. for Python use the module `ldif` in python-ldap:

See docs: [ldif -- LDIF parser and generator](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldif.html)

Comment: Would you be able to provide a solution that actually parses the given data for the string?

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But it would also take me half an hour. So please read the docs: [LDIF parser example](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldif.html#example)

Comment: Then maybe you should have written a comment instead?

Comment: I could delete my answer. No problem. But bear in mind that it's also a bad habit to ask others to do your **complete** home-work.

Comment: I don't think you should delete the answer (I upvoted it). It is the _correct_ answer, but it's also only half an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not quite clear. How far would this get you:

```
    awk  '
            {while (match($0, /rdcPosition: [^ ]*acme#6#[^ ]*/))    {print substr ($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
                                                                     $0  = substr ($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
                                                                    }
            }
    ' file 
rdcPosition: cn=1950,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#8946
rdcPosition: cn=311982,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#97
rdcPosition: cn=914570,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#20
rdcPosition: cn=999546,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#76
rdcPosition: cn=3513,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#2802
```

For your changed request in your comment, how far would this get you? If not satisfied, please become way more specific defining your desired output.

```
awk  '
        {DN = $1 FS $2
         while (match($0, /rdcPosition: [^ ]*acme#6#[^ ]*/))    {print DN, substr ($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
                                                                 $0  =     substr ($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
                                                                }
        }
' file
dn: cn=00fa69bd-bede-4918-a017-b59b0901bb3d,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme rdcPosition: cn=1950,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#8946
dn: cn=010903cd-e92d-4307-bffc-4921379153c0,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme rdcPosition: cn=311982,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#97
dn: cn=01126aa4-af80-401b-8713-29e360868999,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme rdcPosition: cn=914570,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#20
dn: cn=01126aa4-af80-401b-8713-29e360868999,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme rdcPosition: cn=999546,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#76
dn: cn=01126aa4-af80-401b-8713-29e360868999,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme rdcPosition: cn=3513,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#2802
```

Comment: I need the dn: cn= as well with the output

Comment: what do I wrong?
I get other output.
rdcPosition: cn=1950,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>8946 rdcPosition: cn=1950,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>8946/n

Comment: the dn: is not printed ?

Comment: Are you using the sample data from post#1?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following `sed` script (it assumes we're running it with `sed -n`):

```
/^dn:/{                     # this is a "dn" line
    N;                      # append the next line
    s/\n //;                # remove the newline and the space
    x;                      # exchange pattern space with hold space
    /o=acme#6#/p;           # print if pattern space contains our string
    d;                      # delete from pattern space, start next cycle
}
/^rdcPosition:/{            # this is a "rdcPosition" line
    :again;                 # define label for loop
    N;                      # append the next line
    s/\n //;                # remove the newline and the space
    \#</position>#!b again; # if the end tag "</position>" was not read, loop
    /o=acme#6#/H;           # append to hold space if matching what we're looking for
}
${                  # at the very end of input
    x;              # exchange pattern and hold space
    /o=acme#6#/p;   # print if pattern space contains our string
}
```

What the script does is essentially to build up a string in the `sed` "hold space" (general purpose buffer that survives between cycles).  The string will start with the `dn` line and then it will be appended with the `rdcPosition` lines that contain the particular string that we are interested in.

Whenever a new `dn` line is found, or when we are at the end of the input, the hold space is conditionally printed if it contains our string (it may not contain it if none of the `rdcPosition` lines for the current `dn` line matched).

Testing it:

```
$ sed -n -f script.sed file
dn: cn=00fa69bd-bede-4918-a017b59b0901bb3d,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme
rdcPosition: cn=1950,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>8946702990</cn><reqdate>1529318977</reqdate><startdate>1529318977</startdate><enddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>1</newstatus><date>1529318977</date></change><change><date>1529319116</date><previousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>1529481285</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></change></lifecycle></position>
dn: cn=010903cd-e92d-4307-bffc-4921379153c0,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme
rdcPosition: cn=311982,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>9726910833</cn><reqdate>1528120494</reqdate><startdate>1528120494</startdate><enddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>1</newstatus><date>1528120494</date></change><change><date>1528123478</date><previousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change></lifecycle></position>
dn: cn=01126aa4-af80-401b-8713-29e360868999,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme
rdcPosition: cn=914570,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>2068839799</cn><reqdate>1406284665</reqdate><startdate>1406284665</startdate><enddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>0</newstatus><date>1406284665</date></change><change><date>1406284666</date><previousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>1435847283</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></change></lifecycle></position>
rdcPosition: cn=999546,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>7603071057</cn><reqdate>1400325753</reqdate><startdate>1400325753</startdate><enddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>0</newstatus><date>1400325753</date></change><change><date>1400325754</date><previousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>1449224475</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></change></lifecycle></position>
rdcPosition: cn=3513,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=acme#6#<position><cn>2802042129</cn><reqdate>1406284761</reqdate><startdate>1406284761</startdate><enddate>1924902000</enddate><lifecycle><change><previousstatus/><newstatus>0</newstatus><date>1406284761</date></change><change><date>1406284762</date><previousstatus>1</previousstatus><newstatus>3</newstatus></change><change><date>1449224599</date><previousstatus>3</previousstatus><newstatus>6</newstatus></change></lifecycle></position>
```

---

A logically equivalent `awk` script which produces the same output as the `sed` code above:

```
/^dn:/  {
    if (hold ~ "o=acme#6#")
        print hold

    hold = $0;
    getline
    hold = hold substr($0, 2)
    next
}

/^rdcPosition:/ {
    line = $0
    while (line !~ "</position>") {
        getline
        line = line substr($0, 2)
    }

    if (line ~ "o=acme#6#")
        hold = hold ORS line
}

END {
    if (hold ~ "o=acme#6#")
        print hold
}
```

The `substr($0, 2)` calls will strip the leading space off of the broken lines in the input.

Both scripts assumes that the `dn` line is broken into exactly two lines.